# Quitar un número al azar de una lista en Java Error

Tags: java, array

Estoy realizando una aplicación para practicar y necesito que me quite un número al azar de la lista llamada "numeros". He probado con algo así pero no funciona

```
public class Numeros {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(6);
    numeros.add(8);
    numeros.add(10);
    numeros.add(12);
    numeros.add(14);

    Random alazar = new Random(numeros.size());
    int indice = 0;
            for ( int n : numeros )
                 if ( n == numeros) ) {
                      numeros.remove(indice);
                      indice = indice-1;    
                 }
                indice=indice+1;
            }


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno por lo que vi los errores que tenes es que el for no tiene llaves te digo por buena practica y ver mejor tus errores, otra cosa que encontre es que numero tenes que pasarle el indice porque no retorna el integer para la comparacion `numeros.get(indice)`. Y bueno ahora dejo el codigo modificado con las correcciones agregue unos system out print para ver las variables y poder verificar que suceda lo que queres.

```
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(6);
    numeros.add(8);
    numeros.add(10);
    numeros.add(12);
    numeros.add(14);
    numeros.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Fin de add");
    Random alazar = new Random(numeros.size());
    int indice = 0;
            for ( int n : numeros ) {
                 if ( n == numeros.get(indice) ) {
                      numeros.remove(indice);
                      indice = indice-1;  
                      break;
                 }
                indice=indice+1;
            }
    numeros.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razón gracias, si no agrego el break en el if falla cuando la variable indice toma un valor negativo ? por eso lo tengo que agregar?

Comment: si si lo forzas a salir digamos porque al tener un indice negativo salta la excepcion igual no es buena practica lo mejor seria en vez de un for un while con una bandera, que cuando encuentre el valor lo haga salir. Quedate con esa solucion pero no es buena practica salir de un for con un break